# Set bundle display name (CFBundleDisplayName) when adopting SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on a project where we build and package an SDK and ship it to 3rd party iOS development companies to adopt.

In our project we need permission to use the camera of the device. The host app may not have permission to use the camera yet, so when the host app starts up our SDK, we would need to ask for permission to use the camera.

The problem is when the SDK asks for permission the alert title would be: **"MyApp" Would Like to Access the Camera**. As I understand the bundle display name is used to populate the "MyApp" part of the alert title. Is there a way to replace the "MyApp" with the host app's bundle display name? As it isn't possible to set the `CFBundleDisplayName` at build time.

Comment: But it's the application what is asking for permission. The user doesn't care what part of the application is doing it.

Comment: I don't understand your question, "MyApp" will be replaced by the host apps bundle name.  Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @Paulw11 "MyApp" being the SDK's bundle name, but the title shouldn't reference the SDK's bundle name, it should use the host app's bundle display name in the alert title.

Comment: @redent84 The user might get confused. Let's say the host app's name is A and the SDK's name is B. The user is using A, but B is asking for camera permission. The user has no idea who B is as B is embedded within A. So ideally the camera permission alert title should say "A" Would Like to Access the Camera.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
$(EXECUTABLE_NAME) would like to access your Camera
```

Format this string as description key for the NSCameraUsageDescription permission.

For Your Display Name

```
$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your Camera
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not looking for the NSCameraUsageDescription. I already have that in place. That is displayed as the alert message when the app asks for camera permission. The title though is the tricky one. I will give it a shot to use the `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)` rather than the `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`. Thanks